# strongly typed data set throws CastException

Tags: vb.net

When I run this code:
       'Dim Tab As ActDS.ACTDataImportDataTable = CType(Session("WorkData"), ActDS).ACTDataImport'

I get this error:
    'System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code. Message=Unable to cast object of type 'ACTDataImportDataTable' to type 'ActDS'.'

'ActDS' is a strongly type data set and 'ACTDataImportDataTable' is a member of the data set.

What am I doing wrong?

Red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the error message `Session("WorkData")` already is of type `ActDS.ACTDataImportDataTable`.  It looks like the line should just be:

```
Dim Tab As ActDS.ACTDataImportDataTable = 
        CType(Session("WorkData"), ActDS.ACTDataImportDataTable)
```

Comment: Yes Stuart, I see that now. Thanks.